# Update command error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update the attendance of a student given the University Seat Number(USN) and the Subject.
I used the following query and it says none of the rows were affected.

```
Update `Student Attendance` as sa 
JOIN Subjects as s ON sa.`Subject Code`=s.`Subject Code` 
set sa.Attendance ='5' AND sa.`Absent Days`='2017-10-12' 
where sa.USN ='1ks15bt001' AND s.Subject='English';
```

When I ran the the below query alone I got this as the output :

```
  Select sa.USN,s.Subject,sa.Attendance
  From `Student Attendance` as sa 
  JOIN Subjects as s ON sa.`Subject Code`=s.`Subject Code` 
  where sa.USN ='1ks15bt001' AND s.Subject='English';
```

[image: Ouptput]

Schema of Student Table :

```
CREATE TABLE `Student` (
  `USN` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `DOB` date NOT NULL,
  `Dep` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `SEM` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `Class` varchar(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `Student`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`USN`),
  ADD KEY `Dep` (`Dep`);
```

Student Attendance :

```
CREATE TABLE `Student Attendance` (
  `USN` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Subject Code` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `Attendance` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Absent Days` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `Student Attendance`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`USN`,`Subject Code`),
  ADD KEY `ABC` (`Subject Code`);
```

Subjects :

```
CREATE TABLE `Subjects` (
  `Subject` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Subject Code` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `Dep` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `Sem` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `Subjects`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Subject Code`,`Subject`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `bgf` (`Dep`);
```

Comment: My bad, I don't think that will affect the query as that's just a String.

Comment: A schema like this appears to violate the 
[Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) by having multiple date values in a single field. You should create a proper one-to-many relationship so that the number of days here can be properly relational, plus not limited by arbitrary field length constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
Update `Student Attendance` sa join
       Subjects s 
       on sa.`Subject Code` = s.`Subject Code` 
    set sa.Attendance = 5,
        sa.`Absent Days`= '2017-10-12' 
    where sa.USN = '1ks15bt001' AND s.Subject = 'English';
```

Note that `Attendance` is a number, so I removed the single quotes.

Your `set` clause is parsed as:

```
set sa.Attendance = ('5' AND sa.`Absent Days` = '2017-10-12')
```

This is a boolean expression that returns 0 for false and 1 for true.  `0` would indicate that it is false for the row in question.